# MFC CControlBar

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

How do you figure out/determine (either from a control bar, or from the frame it is attached to) which side of the frame a CControlBar is attached to?

I know you can:

1. determine whether a controlbar is floating via BOOL IsFloating( ) const;
2. tell a controlbar which side of a frame it is allowed to connect to  CBRS_ALIGN_TOP, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_TOP

But I don't know how to retrieve which side it has been docked to. Hope there is a method like CurrentlyDockedTo() which would return either CBRS_ALIGN_TOP, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_TOP ...

I am looking for the fastest way to figure out how much gray space is left in the main window ... the size of the gray rectange

Comment: You could get the control bar position and convert it to client coordinates of the container and compare values.

Comment: okay, I was thinking this solution might be my only option ... hoping there would a better option ... a GetAttachSide() method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution to my question. Exactly the answer I needed. The initial hint which led me on the correct path was found in the following post:

[Detecting when a CControlBar's docking state has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523942/detecting-when-a-ccontrolbars-docking-state-has-changed)

The code which I was asking for was the following:

```
CPtrList& list = this->m_listControlBars;
POSITION pos = list.GetHeadPosition();

int total_cntrl_bars_found = 0;
while(pos)
{
  CControlBar* pBar = (CControlBar*)list.GetNext(pos);
  if(pBar)
  {
    if(!pBar->IsFloating())
    {
      total_cntrl_bars_found++;

      int total_matched_styles = 0;
      DWORD bar_style = pBar->GetBarStyle();
      if(bar_style & CBRS_ORIENT_VERT)
      {
        // Then the bar is vertially oriented
        // Will additionally also pass either the
        // right oriented or left oriented check depending
        total_matched_styles++;
      }
      if(bar_style & CBRS_ORIENT_HORZ)
      {
        // Then the bar is vertially oriented
        total_matched_styles++;
      }
      if(bar_style & CBRS_ALIGN_RIGHT)
      {
        // Then the bar is right aligned                                          
        total_matched_styles++;
      }
      if(bar_style & CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT)
      {
        // Then the bar is left aligned
        total_matched_styles++;
      }
      // There is also a check for top align
      // and bottom aligned
    }
  }
}
```

here is some more info on GetBarStyle()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y1e7ff1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use **GetBarStyle**:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y1e7ff1.aspx